# Possible to use Toast Notifications from a regular .Net application?

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, toast

I've recently been checking out the samples for WinRT(C#) for Windows Store. One really cool thing I saw was the Toast Notifications. I can think of a million different uses for them, but not a single one that would also be suitable as a windows store application.

So, is it possible to use Toast Notifications in Windows 8 from regular .Net desktop applications?

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727.aspx#sending_toast_notifications_from_desktop_apps) for more information.

Comment: Doesn't this make us of the Windows.UI.Notifications namespace, which is only available for Windows Store Apps?

Comment: @wollnyst nope, I've used WinRT namespaces in WPF apps

Comment: Wow you save my day. Can you tell me what project configuration you are using?

Comment: It's difficult to do so in comments. You can ask this as a new question and I'll answer it when I get to work and have access to my notes in 14 hours.

Comment: This might be true. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745703/how-can-i-use-the-windows-ui-namespace-from-a-regular-non-store-win32-net-app