# Load UWP library into .NET Framework app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, uwp

There are a number of articles([codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457335/How-to-call-WinRT-APIs-from-NET-desktop-apps), [blog1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx), [blog2](http://www.davidmoore.info/blog/2014/10/17/walkthrough-using-winrt-libraries-from-a-windows-desktop-application/), [forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/40b4f86d-b6d5-430e-a235-7fc003dec4c4/how-to-use-windowsdevicesgeolocation-api-in-a-c-winform-win32-desktop-application-in-windows-10?forum=winforms)) to use WinRT library into .Net Framework console application in Windows 8.

I tried it with UWP in Windows 10. But failed to make it. I struggled to compile without error, but it occurred `BadImageFormatException` in runtime.

This is what I did.

1. Create Console application with .NET Framework 4.6.1 target.
2. Edit .csproj file to add `<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformVersion>`
3. Reference three libraries as below.

   - c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd (shows Windows Runtime 1.4)
   - c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5.1\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll (shows 4.0.10.0)
   - c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll (shows 4.0.0.0)

In contrary to Windows 8 examples, there is error when `System.Runtime.dll` is referenced.

The code is as below. Note that the code is from [Microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/40b4f86d-b6d5-430e-a235-7fc003dec4c4/how-to-use-windowsdevicesgeolocation-api-in-a-c-winform-win32-desktop-application-in-windows-10?forum=winforms).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Geolocator locator = new Geolocator();
        var status = Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();

        if (status != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not null");
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Geoposition pos = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(pos.Coordinate.Accuracy);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("null");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Compilation is OK, and `not null` is displayed in console. So, invocation of library itself seems fine. But `GetGeopositionAsync` cause `BadImageFormatException`.

The exception message detail is as below.

> Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)

I already tried (1) to change build configuration to **x86/x64/AnyCPU** (2) and to set **Copy Local** to true to all references, but same error occurred.

In my opinion, this exception is saying `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` tries to load some dependent library internally but I don't know what it is.

Comment: You can't execute reference assemblies.  Set their Copy Local property to False and use Build > Clean.  Press F5 and now you see the real problem, you don't have version 4.0.10.0 of these assemblies on your machine.  DLL Hell knocking on your door, that's not unusual of course.   Should be retrieved from Nuget but that won't work either, wrong project flavor.  Using the reference assemblies from 4.5 works okay on my machine.

Comment: @HansPassant // thanks, followed by answer and your comment, I changed Copy Local to `false` and Clean project makes it working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the steps working over here, note the subtle differences between yours:

**Step 1**: Add to .csproj file

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**Step 2**: Add reference to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd
```

**Step 3**: Add reference to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
```

Note the differences, v4.5 instead of v4.5.1, and no references to `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll`.

This works fine here (Win10, VS2015).

**Side note**, call to Geolocator will fail regardless:

```
This operation is only valid in the context of an app container. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007109A)
```

It won't be available from within desktop, [only types referenced here are supported in desktop.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn554295(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and I upgraded the version of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform from "5.0.0" to "5.2.2" and my program started working