# HRESULT E_FAIL exception from a WinRT assembly loaded within a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-runtime, winrt-async

Basically I want to access the open, modify and store a [Printing3D3MFPackage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn998063) object. It is only available for UWPs. I added this two references to my WPF project:

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll

Like described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81afc91e-9fa3-4dcf-9eb5-cab9845fcd00/call-winrt-api-from-desktop-app-on-windows-10?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues).

So I do the following. Which is basically creating and storing the object.

```
var package = new Printing3D3MFPackage();
var aa = await package.SaveAsync();
```

Unfortunately, the second line throws the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in oeimporter.exe and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>
> Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a
>   call to a COM component.

Since this works within the UWP, it seems I do something wrong. Could someone help me out?

Comment: try the solution gave by Matthew Beaver on the site you indicated

Comment: I tried. Then I get the following: 

The type 'IAsyncAction' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.

Comment: how are you compiling? x64/x86? did you try to change those settings?

Comment: For my project I'm bound to x64. But UWP should do both. All the other Async commands run without any issue.

Comment: I just created a fresh project where I'm able to switch between x86/x64. Does not work for both.

Comment: I'll try to add it here...I'll get back in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks. I just tried with a Console application for different Frameworks. 4.5-4.6.1. Same result for all of them. Damn

Comment: I think I found the cause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547285/load-uwp-library-into-net-framework-app and here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn554295(v=vs.85).aspx.

In conclusion: Printing3D3MFPackage is not compatible

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need this package so I have to figure out if I have to go for the C++ Library.