# Using ApplicationData in Windows WPF vs UWP

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2015

#### Semi-important Background

I am attempting to change a UWP project to a Windows desktop application so that I can make use of the full .NET Framework 4.5.2. My solution also contains a second project--a Windows Runtime Component--which operates the background tasks. These background tasks write to the `ApplicationData` so that the primary project with the GUI can use the information. I've made the primary project a Windows application rather than a UWP, but one issue remains:

#### The Issue

Any reference to `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values` such as

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Keys.Contains(myDataIndex)
```

results in the following error:

> Error CS0012  **The type 'IPropertySet' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly**
> 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'. ProjectName    C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProjectName\ProjectName\MainWindow.xaml.cs

So, for some reason, VS is confused on what `IPropertySet` is.

#### I've Tried...

Unfortunately, there's nothing starting with `Windows.Foundation` in the list of namespaces under `Assemblies->Framework` in the Reference Manager.

Ok, so it's probably already in there somewhere, right...? I'll just try `using` the required namespace. However, my project cannot find this `Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract` because my project does not allow

```
using Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract
```

though it does find `Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics` and `Windows.Foundation.Metadata`.

When I tried this in *the original UWP version of the project*, it was able to find `Metadata`, `Diagnostics`, and `Windows.Foundation.Collections`. (Curiously enough, the `IPropertySet` interface my Windows app can't find is actually located in [Windows.Foundation.Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211929.aspx)).

This leads me to think that `Windows.Foundation.Collections` is not available in the .NET Framework used by the Windows app, and only in [the UWP .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590967.aspx)...? But if that's the case, why does VS still know about `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values` if it couldn't be used? It seems as if I'm missing something else here.

#### Update

It looks like I just needed to import

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd
```

per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34548528/4163002) to fix the reference issues.

(Strangely, I also had to remove a reference to another `Windows.winmd` file that was at another path. I think that was somehow a result of my attempts to import other things.)

#### Real Question

Ok, I made it work, but it *seems* like I'm cheating by importing `UWP` library stuff. But surely there's a better way?

### TL;DR

**How am I *supposed* to use `ApplicationData` for cross-thread data-sharing in a `WPF` desktop application without other imports?** (And how is it different than a `UWP` application?

Comment: Is this question related to `WPF` or the `UWP`? They are both different technologies...

Comment: @Herdo It's about `WPF`, however the application was originally `UWP`.