# Register a BLE Background Task for Windows Desktop App (Element Not Found for BackgroundTaskRegistration)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm attempting to use the [Windows 10 runtime Bluetooth Low-energy (BLE) APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.aspx) in a Windows desktop `WPF` C# application. The code is mostly based off of the [Bluetooth Advertisement UWP sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement), but I've [added the reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1088916/BLE-on-windows-desktop) to the relevant libraries.

However, I'm running into an issue with the [`BackgroundTaskRegistration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskregistration.aspx) class.

In my `RegisterBackgroundTask` method (essentially identical to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/register-a-background-task#complete-background-task-registration-utility-function)), I attempt to see if my BLE-scanning background task already exists:

```
foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
     {
           if (cur.Value.Name == taskName)
           {
                 // The task is already registered.
                 return (BackgroundTaskRegistration)(cur.Value);

           }
     }
```

But on that first line, calling `BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks` gives:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in BLEProximity.exe
>
> **Msg**: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
>
> **Stack**:    at Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.get_AllTasks()
>      at BLEProject.MainWindow.RegisterBackgroundTask(String taskEntryPoint, String taskName, IBackgroundTrigger trigger, IBackgroundCondition condition) in C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BLEProject\BLEProject\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 421
>
> **Source**: Windows.ApplicationModel

If I bypass the above check for the background task's existence, I will get the same error when I call the `Register()` method of my `BackgroundTaskBuilder`.
Note that I have *no issues* with any of this code when using it in a `UWP` app. For more background, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40047627/uwp-to-windows-app-how-to-use-applicationdata).

My only guess is that this could be related to the app manifest in some way, but I'm fairly new to Windows app development.

Comment: A little tip for future readers looking for this mysterious _element not found_. I have an _ApplicationTrigger_ defined globally (App class variable) in _App.xaml.cs_. I'm calling _Register()_ from _OnLaunched_. When I initialize _applicationTrigger_ globally (_ApplicationTrigger applicationTrigger = new ApplicationTrigger()_ right there where it was defined), I'm getting _element not found_. But when I initialize it from _OnLaunched_ right before _SetTrigger()_ it's working just fine, no exceptions.

Comment: I faced the same error while operating a MSFT demo solution and the only way to properly perform the solution is using the UWP project as the StartUp instead of trying to start from the WPF project. Not 100% associated with OP's question but post this anyway to help beginner of UWP who has 0 idea about what's going on.