# MEF CompositionContainer in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, uwp, mef

How and where to use MEF CompositionContainer in UWP? I tried to use it on OnLaunched() and in the builder of the start page, but the [BadImageFormatException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sV1C.png) error occurred during the startup.

```
        public LoadingWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var container = new CompositionContainer();
    }
```

Comment: maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34548528/578411

Comment: which version of MEF you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP use Nuget package Microsoft.Composition instead System.Composition.
https://blog.softwarepotential.com/porting-to-net-standard-2-0-part-2-porting-mef-1-0-to-mef-2-0-on-net-core/