# Custom Vision ONNX models stopped working with Windows 10 ML

Tags: c#, onnx, windows-machine-learning

I have trained a model using Custom Vision ai. Exporting the model as ONNX file.

In my C# .net core console application I have referenced the windows 10 sdk as described here:
[accessing windows ml from console apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383185/can-windows-ml-learning-models-be-accessed-by-c-sharp-outside-of-uwp)

I am then creating a screenshot and converting it to a SoftwareBitmap -> VideoFrame and finally to a ImageFeatureValue based on the example:
[Using Image as Tensor input for ONNX models](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning/blob/master/Samples/Emoji8/UWP/cs/Emoji8/Services/IntelligenceService.cs)

finally I bind the tensor to my onnx model with:

```
var output = new OnnxModelOutput();
var session = await CreateSession(projectId);
var binding = new LearningModelBinding(session);

binding.Bind("data", imageFile);
binding.Bind("classLabel", output.ClassLabel);
binding.Bind("loss", output.Loss);
```

This worked fine for month! Since a few days it stopped working. It seems that the ONNX binding changed in custom vision ai. If compare an old model to a new one:

#### Old Model

**name**: data
**type**: float32[None,3,224,224]
**denotation**: Image(Bgr8)
Image(s) in BGR format. It is a [N, C, H, W]-tensor.
The 1st/2nd/3rd slices along the C-axis are blue, green, and red channels, respectively.
[input of old ONNX model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqgFm.png)

#### New Model

**name**: data
**type**: float32[None,3,224,224]
**denotation**: Image(Bgr8,Linear,NominalRange_0_255)
Image(s) in BGR format. It is a [N, C, H, W]-tensor.
The 1st/2nd/3rd slices along the C-axis are blue, green, and red channels, respectively
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAwQ2.png)

#### Question

With the current change in the new ONNX model the input binding fails with error:
*Model variable data, expects Float[-1,3,224,224,], but binding was attempted with an incompatible type Image[1174x729].'*

So how to reflect the model input change in c# ???

Comment: This is super interesting! I got the same error too, I think Microsoft has updated the way the model works in the backend.

I cannot update my models anymore and get the same error too.

Comment: Please keep me updated with how this goes mate, this has broken our production.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it!

I downloaded this tool and opened up the model

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning/tree/master/Tools/WinMLDashboard

[image]

And then you need to remove the new metadata properties.
That is to say you need to remove the
Linear,NominalRange_0_255)

So once I removed this, it once more worked!
[image]