# How to send toastnotification in console app

Tags: c#

I'm trying send notification in console app as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062177/is-it-possible-to-send-toast-notification-from-console-application), but when I try to add a reference, I do not have any reference for `Windows -> Core`.

What can I do?

Comment: A "push notification" isn't the same thing as a "toast notification" (a "push notification" is when the notification comes from an external service which is pushed to the client). Are you asking about how you can just display a native Windows notification message that comes from a locally running application?

Comment: ah thx for information. yeah i was asking that how can i send notification in console app.

Comment: Please clarify if you're asking how you can **display** a local Toast notification - **or** if you're asking how to **send** a Push Notification from a console program to Microsoft's Cloud WNS service?

Comment: i m asking how can i display a local toast notification sir