# How to create notification in console app in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, push-notification, console

How do I send a notification to Windows 10 via just a console app and nothing else. I am trying to do this with .NET Framework. I tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062177/is-it-possible-to-send-toast-notification-from-console-application) but when I tried to reference Windows from Windows > Core, there was no such option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a Nuget Package available that provides all the necessary windows references

> Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts.

Once you have installed it you should be able to reference the namespace and add any notification related code

```
using Windows.UI.Notifications;
```

Check out the this [Url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance) for more details