# Send notifications from an app running in the background on w10

Tags: c#, notifications, background-process

I have an API and I want to make an app that calls that API periodicly and if certain conditions are met, then send desktop notifications to the user.

I tried sending toast notifications from a console app, but that didn't work, and from looking at other threads I learned that it isn't possible.

Any suggestions on what project type to use or what library? (.net 6.0)

Comment: It's *possible* to do it from a console app, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062177/is-it-possible-to-send-toast-notification-from-console-application

Comment: Not really. That thread is very outdated. You can not do that using net 6.0