# Win8-10 UWP toast notification from CLI app via WINAPI?

Tags: c#, uwp, command-line-interface, toast

I need to send a simple notification to Windows Notification area from a **tiny** cli app. The issue is, so-called ["officially" recommended way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=desktop) with `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` brings aboard 40Mb of dependencies. **All my code is 23 lines, quite literally**. [There was another way to do it but it does not work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062177/is-it-possible-to-send-toast-notification-from-console-application).

Is there a handy way to somehow do it with PInvoke/dllimport?

Answer (score 1):

The same [Windows.UI.Notifications Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications?view=winrt-22621) exists in [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/) where static libraries are being referenced. When using functions in a static library, only the functions called are being included in the binary, reducing the file size.

I recommend creating a simple C++ DLL project that calls the notification API. Then, P/Invoke that DLL in C#.

(Alternatively you can create a C++/CLI project. But there are extra undocumented steps to reference C++/WinRT when I last tried it)